# i want an additional column to be displayed which will display 1st occurence, 2nd occurence and so on

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table called compare and a column called field in it I want to find the count and the number of occurrence.
I found out the count by using the following command show below

but I want an additional column to be displayed which will display 1st occurrence, 2nd occurrence and so on.

P.S I'm using mysql.

```
 on executing select * from compare I get:
 field
 21
 22
 23
 24
 25
 26
 27
 28
 29
 30
 21
 22

    select field, count(*) as count
    from compare
    group by field
    order by count desc, field








present output
field1, count 
'21\r', '2'
'22\r', '2'
'23\r', '1'
'24\r', '1'
'25\r', '1'
'26\r', '1'
'27\r', '1'
'28\r', '1'
'29\r', '1'
'30\r', '1'
```

expected output

```
 field1, count     occurrence
'21\r', '2'             '1'
'22\r', '2'             '1'
'23\r', '1'             '1'
'24\r', '1'             '1'
'25\r', '1'             '1'
'26\r', '1'             '1'
'27\r', '1'             '1'
'28\r', '1'             '1'
'29\r', '1'             '1'
'30\r', '1'             '1'
'21\r', '2'             '2'
'22\r', '2'             '2'
```

There's a log file of around 50 mb that I wish to compare with itself. I'm importing the data from a text file into one the field1 column of the compare1 table.

on using dan's way:

```
(select field1, count(*) as count,
@row_num := IF(@prev_value=field1,@row_num+1,1) AS Occurence,
@prev_value := field1
from compare1
group by field1
order by count desc, field1);
```

I get:

field1, count, Occurence, @prev_value := field1

```
'21', '2', '1',                         '21'
'22', '2', '1',                         '22'
'23', '1', '1',                         '23'
'24', '1', '1',                         '24'
'25', '1', '1',                         '25'
'26', '1', '1',                         '26'
'27', '1', '1',                         '27'
'28', '1', '1',                         '28'
'29', '1', '1',                         '29'
'30', '1', '1',                         '30'
```

I need:

```
field1, count, Occurence, @prev_value := field1
 21', '2', '1',                         '21'
'22', '2', '1',                         '22'
'23', '1', '1',                         '23'
'24', '1', '1',                         '24'
'25', '1', '1',                         '25'
'26', '1', '1',                         '26'
'27', '1', '1',                         '27'
'28', '1', '1',                         '28'
'29', '1', '1',                         '29'
'30', '1', '1',                         '30'
'21', '2', '2',                         '21'
'22', '2', '2',                         '22'
```

Comment: Can you show us example data and expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What RDBMS are you using? On SQL Server 2008 or newer, you can use windowed functions:

```
SELECT 
    Field,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Field) AS Count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field ORDER BY Field) AS Occurence
FROM Compare
```

On other systems, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Field,
    Count,
    T2.Number
FROM (
    SELECT
        Field,
        COUNT(*) AS Count        
    FROM Compare
) T1 
INNER JOIN Numbers T2 ON T2.Number >= 1 AND T2.Number <= T1.Count
```

In this last query, I assume you have a table called "Numbers", containing one column "Number", with records 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. This table is joined to the Compare table using the actual count of occurences, to generate one record per occurence with an increasing number.

Alternatively, on MySQL you can use variables to number the occurences, eliminating the need to join with a Numbers table:

```
SELECT
    Field,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Compare T2 WHERE T2.Field = T1.Field) AS Count,
    @row_num := IF(@prev_value=Field,@row_num+1,1) AS Occurence,
    @prev_value := Field
FROM Compare T1,
    (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
    (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
ORDER BY Field
```

Comment: i'm using mysql56. also i am using a single table,i'm comparing the numbers within the same table.

Comment: On MySQL I don't think there's an easy way to enumerate rows as in my first example. Thus, the easiest way to do what you want, is to create a Numbers table, that you can use in a join, the way I showed in the 2nd example.

Comment: i wish to perform this operation on 50mb log files.

Comment: i'm using a single table containing the numbers.i have to compare the table with itself.i'm stuck and cant move forward.

Comment: I have included a 3rd query, specifically for MySQL. Try it out, and see if it gets you anywhere.

Comment: Can you post an example of your output when doing this query: `SELECT * FROM Compare`

Comment: You're not writing my query the same way I suggested. Take a look at my 3rd query above: I'm not using the GROUP BY clause, since the COUNT(*) is done as a subquery. This is the problem. If you use GROUP BY, you don't get the duplicate Field values outputted.

Comment: i dont want to use order by i want it in the same order as in the text file. then what can i do?